# How do i add a bunch of open files into a project in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

Can i add a bunch of open files to a project without having to locate each one of them on the disk?

Comment: Um.. well when you create a project you can drag&drop files and folders into the "Project Drawer". Is that what you're referring to or something more specific?

Comment: Also...love the screen-name. Zappa reference?

Comment: I was looking for a Sublime Text 2-like workflow where i can move files around in groups. It gets a bit cumbersome with too many files open in TextMate. Or am i missing some hidden feature here?

Comment: @CleverQuack Haha..thanks. Yes, its a Zappa reference but i'm afraid very few people get it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Is your problem that you have multiple textmate-windows open and want to consolidate them into one window?   - Sorry if i'm off base, and <3 Zappa.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do this from the shell:

`mate fileone filetwo filethree`

Answer (score 1):

(Pardon me for saying so, but your question was a bit ambiguous. I'm assuming that you already have several files independently open in TextMate editors, but each file is not a part of TextMate project.)

The best way I can think of would be to right- or command-click the file name in the top of the editor and then select the enclosing folder from the drop down, then drag the file from the Finder to the project drawer. Not elegant, but that's the best I can think of.